# Qt can't find Qt5Core Qt5Widgets etc

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtgui, qtcore

I downloaded the offline Qt 5.1.1 (32-bit) package from the website.  Just installed it on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I had installed build-essentials prior to the Qt install.

I opened a new Application/GUI project in Qt Creator to play around with.  Haven't added anything to it yet so it just has its default files.  I tried to build it using the Creator Build button and it throws errors:

> :-1: error: skipping incompatible /home/Me/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/lib/libQt5Widgets.so when searching for -lQt5Widgets
>
> :-1: error: cannot find -lQt5Widgets <

Does same thing for the QtCore/Gui files.

Decided to open one of the examples that was included with Qt. Then built it. It also threw the same errors.

What's wrong?  My extra reading said something about adding a `QT += widgets` line in the .pos file but that seems to be there, automatically, inside a version checker.

I thought this was going to be working out of the box?  What have I missed?

Comment: Are you using a simple qmake from the command line ? Do you use QtCreator ? Did you install a version compatible with Qt 5.1.1 ?

Comment: Using Qt Creator 5.1.1.  The package you get from the Qt Project website.  Offline install version.

Comment: It's `QT += widgets`, mind the "s" (not "widget"). Incompatible sounds like you're mixing 32bit and 64bit or something.

Comment: Running an older Lenovo so I downloaded the 32-bit version I thought.  I'll double check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out Frank was right.  While I was correct that I downloaded the 32-bit version of QT I was incorrect about what I was running on the Lenovo for an OS.  I'm actually running the 64-bit Linux.  Didn't think this old thing had the 64-bit loaded on it.  Doh!

Downloaded the 64-bit QT and problem solved.

Thanks Frank for the heads up.